# @value in spring 5 resolves to default value

Tags: spring, spring5

`@Value` in spring 5 resolves to default value even though the property is being loaded from properties

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:/config.properties"})
public class ConfigBean {

}
```

config.properties

```
com.demo.app.authEnabled=true
```

Test class

```
public class Test{

   @Value("${com.demo.app.authEnabled:false}")
   private boolean authEnabled;

   public void method1(){
      System.out.println("authEnabled is: "+authEnabled);
   }
}
```

authEnabled is: false

but if I remove the default value of the property it resolves the actual value from the config.properties

```
@Value("${com.demo.app.authEnabled}")
private boolean authEnabled;
```

authEnabled is: true

Comment: Make sure the property com.demo.app.authEnabled is defined only at one place in the whole project and give it a try.

Comment: What happens if you place the property in `application.properties` instead and delete `config.properties`?